# Continuity of an increasing $f$ in terms of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

The following question is extracted from Royden's Real Anlysis $4$th edition, question $36$ at page $53$:

Let $f$ be an increasing function on the open interval $I$. For $x_0 \in I,$ show that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if there are sequences $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ b_n \}$ in $I$ such that for all $n$, $a_n < x_0 < b_n$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{[f(b_n) - f(a_n)]} = 0.$

I am trying to prove the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction.

Questions:

$(1)$ Are the sequences $\{a_n \} $ and $\{ b_n \}$ monotone?

I can't figure a way to prove this by just using increasing function and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{[f(b_n) - f(a_n)]}=0.$

$(2)$ How to find $\delta$ from our assumptions?

I have a feeling that $\delta$ can be obtained from $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{a_n}$, by I don't know whether the limit exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, let $N$ be a positive integer such that $n\geq N$ implies $f(b_n)-f(a_n)<\varepsilon$.  Let $\delta=\min\{x_0-a_N,b_N-x_0\}$.  Then if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ it follows that $a_N<x<b_N$. Because $x$ and $x_0$ are between $a_N$ and $b_N$ and $f$ is increasing, $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq f(b_N)-f(a_N)<\varepsilon$.

There is no assumption that the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are monotone, or even that they converge (although they would have to converge if $f$ is strictly increasing).  The hypothesis ensures that $f(a_n)$ and $f(b_n)$ get arbitrarily close to one another, and increasingness of $f$ handles the rest.